# Group Policy Object with User Configuration settings only applying on Computers in the same OU - is this normal behavior?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have created a GPO with a User Configuration policy that starts a default program when the user connects through remote desktop. I have linked it to an OU containing the relevant users.

If the computer hosting the remote desktop session is also in the OU then the program is being started automatically as expected. If the computer hosting the remote desktop session is not in the OU then the program isn't starting.

I thought that the User Configuration settings would apply to the users in the OU regardless of whether the computer was in the OU or not, but this isn't happening.

Is this the normal behavior that I am seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This group policy setting exists under both computers and users.  If you edit the policy to set this in both places, that might solve your problem.  (Sorry, I didn't get a chance to test this.)